# How to demux MPTS to SPS

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg, mpeg

I have a live multi-program MPEG-TS stream [MPTS] over IP, I'd like to select just one program from the stream, and output a single-program MPEG-TS stream containing just that program.
is there any software, either open-source or for sale that can do that?

Comment: Better be asked on SU?

Comment: I think it is on topic here, I just don't know the answer on this one.  SU might have someone that knows though.

Comment: Are you trying to rebroadcast someone else's stream?  I think the way this would normally be done is to have a separate stream from the origin.  I'm not sure of any software splitters, though that isn't to say there might not be a commercial streaming server capable of doing it.  Unfortunately I am a Windows streaming media services guy when it comes to live streaming, so I don't know much on the MPEG-TS side of things.

Comment: We're deploying an OTT solution that only supports SPTS as input, in a DVB broadcasting facility that utilizes MPTS streams. need some way to split the MPTS streams to multiple SPTS streams

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Media Server appears to support the functionality you are looking for.  There is a free starter edition or the Extended or Professional editions also support live stream splitting.

Comment: thanks! to complete the answer, can you point to documentation, screenshot or anything to direct at how to setup this feature?

Comment: @AviadRozenhek - unfortunately not, I don't actually have the software.  I was just able to verify from spec sheets that it could a) work with Live MPEG-TS streams and b) split live streams.

Comment: that's what I was looking for, where did you see it in the spec?

Comment: @AviadRozenhek http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/ams/pdfs/ams5-intro-wp.pdf  Also http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-family/buying-guide-comparison.html is useful.

Comment: @AJHenderson Is there any open source project to demux MPTS to SPTS?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde - I have no idea, but you are welcome to ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

[tsMuxer](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/tsMuxeR) should be capable of doing just that. It can handle pretty much any form of transport stream.

Comment: Is there any open source project to demux MPTS to SPTS?

Comment: You can also use ffmpeg

Comment: Well ffmpeg is open source, there are several language bindings including C: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html